# MySQL - Promedio condicional en datos agrupados

Tags: mysql

Soy nuevo en este campo y me quedo corto al tratar de resolver lo que quiero. En una tabla importada desde excel tengo las columnas `<grado, docente, curso, Nota1, Nota2, Nota3, Nota4, Nota5>` algunos campos pertenecientes a las notas contienen una "X" , mi inquietud va de esta manera, quisiera generar una consulta parecida a lo que resulta de lo siguiente:

```
SELECT grado, docente, curso, AVG(Nota1), AVG(Nota2), AVG(Nota3), AVG(Nota4), AVG(Nota5) FROM tabla
GROUP BY docente,curso
```

Sin embargo, el promedio que necesito en cada una de las notas no debe considerar los campos que contienen "X", mi primera opción fue añadir a la consulta anterior un `WHERE Nota1 <> "X"`  y así con todas las notas pero esto también afecta el promedio de las columnas que no tienen ninguna "X" pues restringe toda la fila.

¿Cómo podría resolver este inconveniente?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Por que una X? no sería mejor tener 0 o null? Eso significa que tu campo Nota(n) es un varchar y no int ¿?

Comment: Hola Gonzo, bienvenido a SOes. Te sugiero leer [ask] para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas. Para empezar tu tabla (y probablemente tu base de datos) no se encuentra normalizada, estás rompiendo la 1 forma normal porque estás repitiendo una columna para guardar más valores del mismo tipo. Otra cuestión, el formato en el que se guardar los datos en las tablas no siempre va a coincidir con el formato en que lo quieres mostrar al usuario, antes que tener una `x` es mejor tener un `0` o incluso `null`.

Comment: Te sugiero leer sobre normalización de bases de datos, para evitar complicarte la vida con consultas SQL rebuscadas.

Comment: @M.Gress gracias por tu interés, las notas varían en un rango de 0 a 10, por eso las "x" representan una nota inexistente que no debe ser promediada, intenté reemplazar esa "x" por null usando UPDATE sin embargo todos los campos de todas las columnas se hicieron null así que lo dejé así. De hecho al importar el archivo de Excel a MySQL la columna quedó como un varchar; estoy atento y agradecido a sus sugerencias.

Comment: @MatiasOlivera Hola y gracias, entiendo que estos errores son por mi inexperiencia, a la par que intento resolver esto me informaré mucho mejor

Comment: Las X están en otro campo ?¿ O la X esta en el mismo que el valor de la nota ?¿, porque creo yo que segun lo que comentas el promedio lo esta tomando en base al número de registros Es decir si tienes 10 registros y en un tienes una X te va a sacar el promedio de 10 registros por lógica en la sumatoria no va a sumar X porque no es un valor entero. Si pudieras subir como estan tus tablas creo que sería de mayor ayuda y el resultado que te esta dando la consulta

Comment: @M.Gress en cuanto pueda trataré de subir la tabla y el resultado de la consulta (estoy desde el móvil) lo que si te puedo decir es que tanto los números como la "X" aparecen en las cinco columnas de notas y al usar AVG() si bien es cierto solo suma los números pero los divide entre el total de campos incluido los que contienen "X" haciendo que el promedio disminuya.

Comment: En ese caso podria sugerir subconsultas para obtener cada promedio sin contar los campos que contienen X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberias quitar la condición del where y hacer un IF o NULLIF en cada columna. 
Al devolver NULL en caso de que el campo sea X, AVG no lo promediará.

```
SELECT AVG(NULLIF(Nota1,'X')) FROM tabla
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes. Me parece que esta es una buena respuesta. Si pudieras [edit] tu publicación y poner un ejemplo del punto que estas mencionando creo que quedaria aun mejor.

Comment: Esta sugerencia funcionó perfectamente para mi propósito. Muchas gracias a todos por su tiempo, en adelante, mejoraré mi manera de formular las preguntas.

Comment: Hay alguna manera de verificar mas de un solo valor a no ser considerado dentro del AVG?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías resolver esto usando la sentencia case:

```
SELECT grado, docente, curso,
AVG(CASE nota1 WHEN 'X' THEN NULL ELSE nota1 END) as 'Nota 1',
AVG(CASE nota2 WHEN 'X' THEN NULL ELSE nota2 END) as 'Nota 2',
AVG(CASE nota3 WHEN 'X' THEN NULL ELSE nota3 END) as 'Nota 3',
AVG(CASE nota4 WHEN 'X' THEN NULL ELSE nota4 END) as 'Nota 4',
AVG(CASE nota5 WHEN 'X' THEN NULL ELSE nota5 END) as 'Nota 5'
FROM docs;
```

Te adjunto el ejemplo: [Ejemplo en Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/160aec)

Comment: También he probado esta sugerencia y cumple con el propósito, gracias.